# Adding deep Links using react-router

Tags: react-router

Using the below Route configuration -

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
   <Route name="Home" path="/" component={BaseLayout}>
      <Route name="Gateways" path="/gateways" component={DashboardLayout}>
        <Route name="Login" path="/login" component={Login}/>                      
        <Route name=":id" path="/gateways/:id">
            <IndexRoute name="Dashboard"  component={ViewGateWay}/>                                 
            <Route name="Access Points" path="/accesspoints" component={AccessPoints}>                              
                <Route name=":id" path="/:id" component={ViewAccessPoint}/>
            </Route>
            <Route name="Devices" path="/devices" component={Devices}>                              
                <Route name=":id" path="/:id" component={ViewDevice}/>
            </Route>
        </Route>
        <IndexRoute component={Gateways} />
     </Route>                    
     <IndexRedirect to="Login" />
   </Route>
</Router>
```

Using `name` in the  Route for breadcrumbs. Have a side menu which have links to `/gateways/:id`, `/gateways/:id/devices`, `/gateways/:id/accesspoints`, further the last two have links to individual devices and access points using `Link` as `/gateways/:id/devices/:id` and `/gateways/:id/accesspoints/:id`. When I am giving the link in the side menu as

```
<Link to="/gateways/${this.props.params.id}/accesspoints">Access Points</Link>
```

OR

```
<Link to="/accesspoints">Access Points</Link>
```

I am not getting the correct page. Same goes with the devices link. I am trying to achieve the below API's along with  breadcrumb.

```
home/gateways/GW_ID1/dashboard
home/gateways/GW_ID1/accesspoints
home/gateways/GW_ID1/accesspoints/GW_AP1
home/gateways/GW_ID1/devices
home/gateways/GW_ID1/devices/GW_DV1
```

What is the correct way to Link ?  Not using any handler.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of brainstorming, came up with a solution what I wanted to achieve

```
    <Route name=":gid" path="/gateways/:gid">
        <Route name="Dashboard"  path="/gateways/:gid/dashboard"   component={ViewGateWay}/>                                    
        <Route name="Access Points" path="/gateways/:gid/accesspoints"  component={AccessPoints}>                               
            <Route name=":apid" path="/gateways/:gid/accesspoints/:apid" component={ViewAccessPoint}/>
        </Route>
        <Route name="Devices" path="/gateways/:gid/devices"  component={Devices}>                               
               <Route name=":did" path="/gateways/:gid/devices/:did" component={ViewDevice}/>
        </Route>
</Route>
```